# How to install pycsw on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, pycsw

I have Apache 2.2.22 running on Ubuntu Server 12.04.5 LTS. Following the [`pycsw` install instructions](http://docs.pycsw.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-on-ubuntu-xubuntu-kubuntu) I issued these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pycsw/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pycsw pycsw-cgi
```

After that, if I try to access the address `http://localhost/pycsw` I get a `403` error in return.

The install instructions seem to be incomplete, what else is needed to get `pycsw` running on Ubuntu?

**Edit**: This was just a matter of pointing to the wrong addresses. The main page seems to be in the `tests` folder:

`http://localhost/tests`

And the service itself is executed directly through the `csw.py` file:

`http://localhost/csw.py`

Comment: did you do # cd pycsw/etc/dist
# sudo ./install_pycsw.sh

Comment: Hi Ian, there is no `dist` folder inside `etc`.

Comment: I will leave this question up, other folk might do the same mistake.